# Getting the HAVING clause in ClojureQL query

Tags: clojure, clojureql

I'm trying to build the following query in ClojureQL:

```
SELECT ixIso, MIN(IF(dtDespatched, fQuantity, 0)) AS quantity
  FROM IsoItem WHERE fQuantity > 0
  GROUP BY ixIso
  HAVING quantity < 1
```

I've been trying variations of the following code, basing it [off this IRC log](http://raynes.me/logs/irc.freenode.net/clojureql/2011-01-12.txt) I found.

```
(-> (cql/table DB :IsoItem)
    (cql/select (cql/where (> :fQuantity 0)))
    (cql/aggregate [[ "MIN(IF(IsoItem.dtDespatched, IsoItem.fQuantity, 0))" :as :quantity]]
                   [:ixIso] )
    (cql/select (cql/where (< :quantity 1))))
```

However, the query it keeps giving me is:

```
SELECT IsoItem.ixIso,MIN(IF(IsoItem.dtDespatched, IsoItem.fQuantity, 0)) AS quantity FROM IsoItem WHERE (fQuantity > 0) AND (quantity < 1) GROUP BY IsoItem.ixIso
```

I feel like I must be missing something so basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it may have been a bug in ClojureQL itself, I've updated my project.clj to include ClojureQL 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT rather than 1.0.0 and it's corrected the issue.